# Inaccurate currency displayed in Google Rich Snippet

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets, products

We have managed to display information in the SERPs from our Schema.org markup, however, the information is incorrect.

The page shows up in the SERPs, displaying USD rather than GBP

We have different currency options on the site, but have marked up the `priceCurrency` as GBP.

What could be the reason for the inaccurate details to show?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where is your "country" tab set to in google webmaster tools > search traffic > international targeting?

Comment: It is set to the United Kingdom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Not a Schema issue, it's a website and  Google issue*

The problem you are experiencing is pretty common and a [side effect of GEO IP detection](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78434/side-effects-of-customising-a-users-currency-based-upon-their-ip/). The issue that your encountering is occurring due to the fact that your site is using some type of IP [Geolocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_software) service, often known as [GEOIP](https://www.quora.com/How-does-GeoIP-work).

In short your site is automatically detecting where a site visitor is located and then serving them with the correct currency, and obviously you are serving the Googlebot with US currency, because the majority of Google's crawlers are located in the US.

*Google's Data Centres*

Google's crawler operates on a [large volume of IP addresses](http://tools.tracemyip.org/search--isp/googlebot), and [Google operates from multiple data centres](https://www.google.com/about/datacenters/inside/locations/index.html) throughout the world:

> - America
>
>   - Berkeley County, South Carolina
>   - Council Bluffs, Iowa
>   - Douglas County, Georgia
>   - Jackson County, Alabama
>   - Lenoir, North Carolina
>   - Mayes County, Oklahoma
>   - Montgomery County, Tennessee
>   - Quilicura, Chile
>   - The Dalles, Oregon
> - Asia
>
>   - Changhua County, Taiwan
>   - Singapore
> - Europe
>
>   - Dublin, Ireland
>   - Eemshaven, Netherlands
>   - Hamina, Finland
>   - St Ghislain, Belgium

*Google does not crawl websites from the UK*

As far as I know Google does not have any UK based servers, but they do have servers in Ireland, most likely for [tax haven](http://www.taxjustice.net/2016/02/16/why-google-and-other-multinationals-are-still-not-paying-their-fair-share-of-corporation-tax/) reasons, as Ireland is know for its [Double Irish Arrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Irish_arrangement) that allows big companies to pay lower taxes for its products and services, something that is constantly in the UK press, often referred to as [tax avoidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/policies/tax-evasion-and-avoidance) by politicians.

*Anyway...*

Google crawling will never occur from a UK based server, since the majority of crawling occurs from servers located in the states, other countries outside of the UK, but besides... even if Google did have a UK crawler, Google doesn't have a feature where you can select a preferred crawl location in any-case.

*Incorrect currency May Affect Your Local Rankings*

If your main target region is the UK, then Google finding US dollar can and most likely affect your rankings, Since Google thinks your main region is US.

> [SOURCE](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#2)
>
> Other signals. Other sources of clues as to the intended audience of
>   your site can include local addresses and phone numbers on the pages,
>   the use of local language and currency, links from other local sites,
>   and/or the use of Google My Business (where available).

*Replicate my Findings*

You can replicate this issue by connecting to a VPN, or Proxy located in the US and then using a cookieless browser (important since your site is storing last used currency as a cookie) or [Google Chrome incognito](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?source=gsearch&hl=en), you can clearly see that it is automatically assigning the currency.

*Possible Fix*

The most obvious thing would be to ignore the IP addresses of Googlebot, or the user agent, however this is not recommended by Google, since it could be detected as a [form of cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355). You should always treat the Googlebot as a visitor, not a bot.

So, you could always use that solution but obviously its not approved by Google. So I wouldn't recommend the above solution to anyone. You can approach this by setting up your site as a [Multi-regional and multilingual](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en) website.

Or alternatively use multiple Schema markup to determine the currency, therefore Google should understand the website has multiple currencies and return the correct results depending where the user is in the world.

> [SOURCE:](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/78609/20604)
>
> This would allow you to serve all currencies in your markup, hide
>   those that weren't valid for the current user/ip through CSS/JS and
>   still have Google understand what you're doing:
>
> ```
> <div class="curr-gbp" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
>   <!--price is 1000, a number, with locale-specific thousands separator
>       and decimal mark, and the $ character is marked up with the
>       machine-readable code "USD" -->
>   <span class="usd" itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span>
>   <span class="usd" itemprop="price" content="1000.00">1,000.00</span>
>   <span class="gbp" itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP">&pound;</span>
>   <span class="gbp" itemprop="price" content="750.00">750.00</span>
>   <span class="aud" itemprop="priceCurrency" content="AUD">$</span>
>   <span class="aud" itemprop="price" content="1500.00">1,500.00</span>
> </div>
> ```
>
> You set the class on the containing div to the currency you've
>   selected for the user and then hide the other options through CSS:
>
> ```
> .curr-gbp .usd, .curr-gbp .aud { display: none; }
> .curr-usd .gbp, .curr-usd .aud { display: none; }
> .curr-aud .usd, .curr-aud .gbp { display: none; }
> ```
>
> Google [should then recognise](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/) the mark-up and display it as
>   appropriate in its listings.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, this really has helped my understanding of  this issue.

One question, what is the point of indicating the currency if this appears to have no effect on the SERPs?

Comment: Also, with the solution regarding marking up all currencies and only showing the correct currency based on the user's IP, is that not similar to the approach we already have? Would Google still not use USD in the SERP's?

Comment: Not exactly, because Google will see all the currencies in the source. Current they are only seeing one currency. A method not discussed is that you could simply ask the user with a pop up if they would like to change to USD, by giving them the choice the default will automatic be GBP.

Comment: So the priceCurrency mark-up, which is what we use on to GBP, should that not be indicating to Google the correct currency?

Comment: On category product pages you only have `<option value="GBP">GBP &#163; </option>` in the source, and on product pages you have `<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />` and `<meta itemprop="price" content="2.95" />` and `<div class="amount">$4.13</div>` So the fact on a lot of pages you have fixed USD pricing and hidden GBP values on other pages, Google is deciding that US dollar is best suited.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you saying that even though we state that the currency is GBP, because $ is displayed in the text, Google uses this?

Comment: The major problem I now see is that you have £ and $, but only `<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="GBP" />`, you need to use multiple offers, see this: https://www.bybe.net/files/pro-webmasters/currency-test.html and run it through Google's rich testing tool. Your see multiple currencies. Currently your telling Google you have GBP currency, yet its seeing dollar symbols all across your site, its conflicting and Google is doing what it thinks you want. So, add multiple offers first, see if that works.

Comment: After many many months of including this meta data for the currencies supported on my website, the Google SERP microdata still displays in the wrong currency. So it might just generally be that Google SERPs don't currently respect this data, and the pages must be served on different URLs (rather than using a pure GEOIP solution). Which is annoying!

Comment: What's the URL?